# How to 'json parsing in tableView Cell between tableView'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm creating a simple weather app.
Using three ViewControllers,
The tableView in the first view displays the name and image of each country.
If you click tableViewCell, tableView of city list of country displayed in cell appears. (ex. us -> LA)
There is a problem here. In the first tableview, I want to parse the counties.json file and then press cell to get the cities of the country.

So far I have completed the first table view (representing counties). However, when I clicked on each cell, I could not represent the city for each cell.

```
import UIKit

class WorldListController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var worlds: [World] = []
    var dataSource: WorldDataSource?
}

extension WorldListController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 65
    }
}

extension WorldListController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let jsonDecoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        guard let dataAsset: NSDataAsset = NSDataAsset(name: "countries") else {
            return
        }

        do {
            self.worlds = try jsonDecoder.decode([World].self, from: dataAsset.data)
            let worldsList = worlds
            print(worldsList[0].countryImage)
            self.dataSource = WorldDataSource(worlds: worldsList)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        tableView.dataSource = dataSource
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.reloadData()
    }


}
```

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class CityListViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var cities: [City] = []
    var dataSource: CityDataSource?

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController,
            let destination = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? WeatherViewController {
            destination.cities = cities
        }
    }
    @IBAction func backPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension CityListViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let jsonDecoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        guard let dataAsset: NSDataAsset = NSDataAsset(name: "korea") else {
            return
        }

        do {
            self.cities = try jsonDecoder.decode([City].self, from: dataAsset.data)
            let citiesList = cities
            self.dataSource = CityDataSource(cities: citiesList)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        tableView.dataSource = dataSource
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension CityListViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

class WorldDataSource: NSObject {
    let worlds: [World]

    init(worlds: [World]) {
        self.worlds = worlds
    }
}

extension WorldDataSource: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return worlds.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: WorldCell.self)) as! WorldCell
        let world = worlds[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = world.countryName
        cell.countryImage.image = UIImage(named: world.countryImage)
        return cell
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

class WorldCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var countryImage: UIImageView!

    static let identifier = "WorldCell"

    var name: String? {
        didSet {
            nameLabel.text = name
        }
    }

    var countrtImg: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            countryImage.image = countrtImg
        }
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

class CityCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cityName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tempLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rainfallProbabilityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var state: UIImageView!

    static let identifier = "CityCell"

    var name: String? {
        didSet {
            cityName.text = name
        }
    }

    var temp: Int? {
        didSet {
            tempLabel.text = "\(temp ?? 0)"
        }
    }

    var rainfallProbability: Int? {
        didSet {
            rainfallProbabilityLabel.text = "\(rainfallProbability ?? 0)"
        }
    }

    var stateImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            state.image = stateImage
        }
    }
}
```

I've parsed "countries.json" in tableView like the first code. But in the second code, we are just parsing "korea.json" apart from the parsed countries. Whether you press USA or France, cities in korea appear. How do I get USA cities when I press USA, France cities when I click on France?

Comment: past your country uitabelview `cellRowAt` method code

Comment: In `CityListViewController` which one of them are you using as `tableView's` `dataSource' , `self.cities` or `self.dataSource`?

Comment: Add tableView dataSource code.

Comment: What you have is a one-to-many relationship between Country and City and this means City needs to have a reference to which Country it belongs. Do you have a country property in your City struct/class or is it a key when fetching the json for cities?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson /There is no counties property in the City structure. I think contries.json and usa.json / france.json are separate, so I did not create the counties property

Comment: @PGDev 
already add tableView dataSource

Comment: So then it’s just a matter of selecting and decoding the city json file that corresponds to the selected country.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson
Thank you. Joakim ..! Could you show me some examples? It does not make sense.

Comment: In the same way you have a prepare(for segue) in your city list Vc you need one in your world list Vc and a property in the city list Vc for the selected country that you set in the prepare(for segue). Then open your json using that property instead of the hard coded value you have now.